# Perform a click to other buttons objective c

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, ibaction

So how can i make a button click other buttons in objective c for iOS? I use xcode.

```
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *save1;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *save2;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *save3;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *save4;
```

These are the buttons, I want that button "save4" click button "save1", "save2" & "save3".

I understand the actions and outlets and I have that all connected, but I just wan't the code to click other buttons, the problem I have is that those buttons are on another view and I tried many code but they don't work. Here is a download link: [Download](http://dropbox.com/s/l6o07m48npxknt4/Cluedo.zip?dl=0)

Comment: No, you don't want one button to "click" other buttons. You want a button tap (not click) to perform various actions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused between "Outlets" and "Actions". For handling button clicks, you must define "Actions" for your buttons. For eg, write the following code in your view controllers .m file:

```
- (IBAction) saveOnePressed:(id)sender{
// Button one is pressed. Do your actions here.


}
```

And connect your button to this action.

EDIT:

As per rmaddys suggestion:

You can define the Action for your fourth button as the following:

```
- (IBAction)saveFourPressed:(id)sender{

// Here you can call all the other 3 actions

[self saveOnePressed:nil];
[self saveTwoPressed:nil];
//......
 }
```

Comment: Given the OP's apparent confusion, this answer can be more helpful if you show an example of how the action for "save4" can call the other actions.

Comment: I understand the actions and outlets and I have that all connected, but I just wan't the code to click other buttons, the problem I have is that those buttons are on another view and I tried many code but they don't work. 

Here is a download link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6o07m48npxknt4/Cluedo.zip?dl=0